# Find Substring Matches Between Two Files

Tags: python, string, list, file, match

I have a list of movie titles and a list of names.

Movies:

- Independence Day
- Who Framed Roger Rabbit
- Rosemary's Baby
- Ghostbusters
- There's Something About Mary

Names:

- Roger
- Kyle
- Mary
- Sam

I want to make a new list of all the movies that match a name from the names list.

- Who Framed Roger Rabbit (matched "roger")
- Rosemary's Baby (matched "mary")
- There's Something About Mary (matched "mary")

I've tried to do this in Python, but for some reason it isn't working. The resulting file is empty.

```
with open("movies.csv", "r") as movieList:
    movies = movieList.readlines()

with open("names.txt", "r") as namesToCheck:
    names = namesToCheck.readlines()

with open("matches.csv", "w") as matches:
    matches.truncate(0)

    for i in range(len(movies)):
        for j in range(len(names)):
            if names[j].lower() in movies[i].lower():
                matches.write(movies[i])
                break

    matches.close();
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Your code works for me. Did you try printing out `movies` and `names` and see if they are proper lists?

Comment: Please post an example of your files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that you aren't getting any results is likely that when you call `readlines()` on a file in Python it gives you a list of each line with a newline character, `\n`, attached to the end. Therefore your program would be checking if `"roger\n"` is in a line in the movies files rather than just `"roger"`.

To fix this, you could simply add a `[:-1]` to your `if` statement to only check the name and not the newline:

```
if names[j].lower()[:-1] in movies[i].lower():
```

You could also change the way you read the names file by using `read().splitlines()` to get rid of the newline character like this:

```
names = namesToCheck.read().splitlines()
```

Answer (score 1):

This works ....

```
Movies="""Independence Day
Who Framed Roger Rabbit
Rosemary's Baby
Ghostbusters
There's Something About Mary
"""

Names="""Roger
Kyle
Mary
Sam"""

with StringIO(Movies) as movie_file:
    movies=[n.strip().lower() for n in movie_file.readlines()]
with StringIO(Names) as name_file:
    names=[n.strip().lower() for n in name_file.readlines()]

for name in names:
    for film in movies:
        if film.find(name) is not -1:
            print("{:20s} {:40s}".format(name,film))
```

Output:

roger                who framed roger rabbit
mary                 rosemary's baby
mary                 there's something about mary